# Installing Ubuntu from usb pendrive on hard disk

Tags: system-installation

I have downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 desktop iso. I wish to install this on my laptop and replace the existing windows xp (SP3) with ubuntu. Unfortunately I do not have a working CDROM drive  on my laptop.

Is it possible to copy the ISO file on pendrive and then install Ubuntu on hard disk? I don't wish to run Ubuntu off the pen drive and would rather install it on hard disk itself.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible to create bootable USB from an ISO within Windows. It is not exactly by copying an ISO to the USB key, however it's almost as simple. The instructions are located here: [How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows | Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Afterwards you can boot from the USB as if you booted from a CD and proceed to install Ubuntu on your hard disk.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible. There are two ways of installing Ubuntu in pendrive.

1. Completely extract the Ubuntu ISO to the pendrive using Universal Linux Installer. Check the [link](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) for complete step by step guide.
2. You can copy the ISO file to the Pendrive and boot it using GRUB4LINUX. Its complicated to setup and need lot of more effort compared to first one.

Answer (score -1):

I would be careful about using the Pendrive application.  I pretty confident that the Pendrive installer installed "Funmoods" on my machine.  I was already hesitant to install the application and pressed cancel.

The installer misbehaved and continued to install something.  It messes with every browser that is installed and leaves DLLs in User//Appdata/...